# Reset Object on Exception

Tags: php, exception

I have an objet that I would like to reset when an exception is thrown, is there any way to do this?

For example I have this class:

```
class TestClass{

    public $value = 0;

}
```

I then create an instance of the class and set it's `$value` to 100 in the `try`, then throw an error like this:

```
$test = new TestClass();

try{
    $test->value = 100;
    throw new Exception("Error!", 100);
}catch(Exception $ex){
    var_dump($test);
}
```

The `var_dump` will be be called since an error is throw, but when the dump displays, `$value` is still `100` I was hoping that it would still be `0` for this test, but it is not. Is there a way to reset the instance when an error is thrown?

Comment: Don't use magic methods, they're horrible for readability and future code re-use. You don't usually want *every* property of an object being mutable.

Comment: No, using magic methods like __get() or __set() is generally frowned upon as poor practice. Be explicit in your method calls and property updating - magic is bad 'mmkay?

Comment: No problem - the more you hide within your code via 'magic', the harder it is for other devs to pick up, work with and debug in the future.

Comment: After looking around I found that the best way would be to just re instantiate in the catch

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Why on earth would that be the best way? It's up to **your object** to encapsulate it's state and original state, not some procedural code in a catch, and providing an object API like my answer shows that *makes sense* would be much more beneficial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note**: Since writing this originally my opinion has changed. The object's original value is not for itself to hold - that is for the implementation *using* the object to decide - which may change depending on where in the project it is used. The alternative is to have that value set for the object in a factory; allowing multiple factories for different scenarios.
>
> "I have an object that I would like to reset when an exception is thrown, is there any way to do this?"

Yes, you'll need to state what the original value is that you want to go back to. That's a perfect candidate for a class [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php), although you can just set it in another variable if you so wish. I'm going to use a class constant.

```
class TestClass
{
    const RESET_VAL = 100;

    /**
     * @var int The object's value
     */
    protected $value = 100;

    /**
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Reset $value back to it's initial state
     *
     * @see self::RESET_VAL
     */
    public function resetValue()
    {
        $this->value = self::RESET_VAL;
    }
}
```

What's changed here and why? Well, don't use `public` as your [access modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)! Why? Because you're not writing 'c-style' structs here. You're introducing global state into your application any time you have a public property. You should have methods, like `setValue()`, in order to change the state of an object.

There's also the `resetValue()` method. Why are we using that, instead of just calling `$testClass->resetValue(TestClass::RESET_VAL);`? Well, because that's not object oriented programming - calling a method on the object *is*.

Your final code would look like this, using the above class:

```
$test = new TestObject;

try 
{
    $test->setValue(55);

    /** Somewhere down the object chain you get an exception... **/
    throw new Exception("Uh oh...");
} 
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $test->resetValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I see is to have a `reset()` method, and call it in the exception handler.

```
try{
    $test->value = 100;
    throw new Exception("Error!", 100);
}catch(Exception $ex){
    $test->reset();
    var_dump($test);
}
```

I don't see how you could do it in a very general way. You could also do something like;

```
class TestClass {
  // ....
  public function reset() {
    // ....
  }

  public function tryToDoSomething($x) {
    try {
      // something with $x that might throw
    } catch (Exception $x) {
      $this->reset();
    }
  }
}
```